# Can you say "the dessert eats well"?

Tags: middle-voice

I heard that a food critic (who is British male) made a comment on a dish like this:

> It looks very pretty, but it doesn't eat very well.

The expression amazed me as I never knew food can be a subject of verb *eat*. I couldn't find such a usage in any dictionaries. Is it something poetic rather than correct English?

Comment: Perhaps somewhat similar to *"This car drives well", "This steak tastes good"*.

Comment: Yes, food critics do talk that way--it is common in their register.

Comment: Aha. Thanks @F.E. and all those who posted answers. BTW, it's [Charles Campion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Campion) who said this.

Comment: As a native English speaker, this sounds weird to me, although I can figure out what it means. It sounds like the writer is trying to sound fancy.

Comment: This is certainly grammatically correct though the meaning of a literal reading would be rather different than what was intended. You rather have to give some poetic license to the writer/speaker if you want to ascertain the intended meaning. Either way I would consider this a poor sentence, perhaps with some intent to sound overly posh. I would not however recommend writing or speaking in this way in any normal situation unless you were trying to create some particular effect.

Comment: It sounds a little tongue-in-cheek to me.

Comment: For a non native speaker it is important to know that this is very pretentious and not 'talking posh'. Avoid.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

English is cool, in that words can often be "bent" to suit our purposes.

Context is everything. Can you use *food* as a subject of the word *eat*? Sure you can; you just saw it done. But I'm not surprised you heard this obscure usage being uttered by a food critic. It's their job to eat, taste, and comment, and they will form their sentences accordingly.

I found a similar usage in the [comments of a wine critic](http://vinvinowine.blogspot.com/2009/05/2007-domaine-de-la-colline-st-jean.html):

> *On the second night the wine seemed to offer up even more dark fruit, suggesting that a year or so in bottle may deliver even more. **This is not to say that the wine doesn't drink well now** – compared to a few of the 2007 Cotes du Rhones I have had, this wine does not show too much heat or acidity at this stage*.

I agree with Ryan's answer above; I, too, would not recommend using this wording too often. After, say, visiting a McDonald's, you probably don't want to say:

> *The French fries were edible, but the Big Mac didn't eat very well*.

no matter how mediocre you found the food – unless you *want* to sound like a food critic for some reason.

The sentence isn't grammatically flawed, but it's not how most people would say it.

Comment: I'd prefer writing *The dessert tastes well* to avoid ambiguity. I also think that's a common expression as compared to the one in question.

Comment: @Maulik - No.  _The dessert tastes good._  Not _well_.  _Good_ here is a quality of the dessert, revealed by tasting, so you need an adjective.  It's different from _the dessert eats well_, in which you are qualifying the process of eating, not the dessert itself.

Comment: @MaulikV - I would see slight ambiguity as the point.  A food critic is probably paying attention to texture as well as taste, and saying the dessert "doesn't eat very well" can encompass both very concisely.

Comment: @Dylan - I think you hit the nail on the head. Foodies must "appreciate the gestalt" and not just the taste.

Comment: @DavidWallace point taken. btw, *well* is **also** an adjective! And something tastes well is [not utterly incorrect](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/787543-only-cooked-time-tastes-well).

Comment: "Well" as an adjective means "not sick", for people and animals.  It doesn't apply to dessert.  You'd never say that a dessert wasn't sick.  @MaulikV

Answer (score 13):

Some verbs are used with 'patient focus'. In the *[Grammar of Discourse](http://books.google.cz/books?id=GHRkak8j8x8C&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=%22washes%20easily%22&source=bl&ots=t5Rc-MZoPw&sig=21SaB7a3oHo59K3GKHtMa_g7yKo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=w_1fVKC0OIfuPMmrgZgF&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22washes%20easily%22&f=false)*  Longacre gives examples such as *The article reads smoothly* and *My new car drives nicely*.

*It doesn't eat very well* appears to be this type of construction, but I have never heard EAT used in this way.

Comment: Exactly, I just wrote in my comment. *tastes well...* sounds better. +1

Comment: It's not common usage: I'd describe it as food-critic jargon

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, this is a structure known in linguistics as "middle voice" (although you don't often see that term used when talking about English grammar). In many languages it's explicitly marked, but in English it usually takes the form of a verb that looks like it's active voice but has passive meaning.

As other people have already said, "the dessert eats well" is grammatical, although for many people sounds a little bit forced. There are, however, plenty of other examples of the middle voice in English where it's alive and well. A simple example:

Active voice: "The ball broke the window" (the ball is subject and is causing the action of breaking)

Passive voice: "The window was broken by the ball"

Middle voice: "The window broke" (the window is subject, but *underwent* the action of breaking)

Or

Active voice: "The sun melted the ice" (the sun is subject and causing the action of melting)

Passive voice: "The ice was melted by the sun"

Middle voice: "The ice melted" (the ice is subject, but underwent the action of melting)

In each case, the middle voice form is derived from a transitive active voice verb, but with the object of the transitive form being used as the subject of the intransitive middle voice form.

Comment: Do you think that the concept of  *middle voice*  is relevant to modern English?

Comment: Can all transitive verbs be used in middle voice structure in theory?

Answer (score 2):

Saying a phrase such as "eats well" is a fairly poetic usage. It is more stylistic of British English than American English. From my American point of view, it sounds a bit awkward. It is a matter of opinion if such a sentence is correct, but in general, I would avoid using the phrase in this way.

Comment: I don't think it's so much poetic as jargon.

Answer (score 0):

On those lines, it irks me to hear someone say "Oh, she takes a good photo!" when what they mean is "She looks good in a photo!"

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. Once you have enough reputation, you'll be able to comment, but answers should be answers and not commentary.

Comment: Why does this "irk" you, john? You don't like seeing language evolve? (Incidentally, this could be a comment, as @Coleen suggests – or it could be the start of an interesting question.)

Comment: @J.R. Language can evolve and by not embracing stupid usage it can get better rather than worse. :)

Comment: @JamesRyan: "better" and "worse" by whose standards?

Answer (score 0):

It is no more strange than to say the food "looks" very pretty. It has no eyes with which to see, or certainly none that remain operational at this point, I hope! I
 look at the food and behold it to be pretty, so we says it "Looks pretty". "Eats well" is quite parallel, in this sentence.

Comment: Not all verbs can be used idiomatically / equally idiomatically in the middle voice. The 'eat' usage is more modern than the 'look' one, and more care has to be taken with particular examples.